# My Eight Pieces Together

Tags: riddle

My first is part of your digestive system, but you sometimes use only half of me.
My second is sometimes called what people sometimes call the shark hanging in the Smithsonian.
My third is my mom, once removed from Matilda and re-moved again.
My fourth is a greeting to my friend who is named after the end.
My fifth is a really fast run.
My sixth is in the number three.
My seventh can replace my first and my last.
My eighth is the last 2 of my dad's essay topics.

**What is my all?**

Note: I edited some of the clues for clarification.

Hint:

> The answer is NOT punctuation marks. There is an actual obvious answer once you know the answers.

Hint 2:

> In the hint for my third, the re-moved again part has significance.

Hint 3:

> At least two of the clues are the same.

Hint 4:

> My second is made of parts...
> My third is re-moved again.
>  My sixth is not in #3
>  My seventh requires the others.

Comment: Hey man, are you still around? I really want to see the answer to this!

Comment: @BaileyM Sorry, I've been gone for I while... I'm so ready to post the answer but after the bounty ends

Comment: In the meantime, can you add another clue?

Comment: @Bailey M Yes, I will.

Comment: Your Hint 1 gives me the impression the final answer is something that we have to arrive at based on the answers to the clues i.e. a two-step solution. So, to what do the clues **directly** point/lead to (step 1)?
1. A phrase/word consisting of at least two words including/excluding punctuation marks.
2. A string of punctuation marks.
3. A single word, without any punctuation marks.
4. None of the above.

Comment: @awesomepi Will the "geography" tag apply to this riddle?

Comment: @kanchirk No. For sure not.

Comment: A valiant attempt was made, to be sure. Yet still...no one has any idea what we're doing here. :P

Comment: I wonder if awesomepi is going to answer @Meet's question above?  That might help with the solving.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

My first was answered by @A.D.

> A colon

My second was answered by @GentlePurpleRain in the comments

> A hyphen (a high fin)

My third was technically half-answered by @A.D

> A tilde then re-moved (or shifted) is a "`"

My fourth was answered by @A.D.

> A hyphen

My fifth was also answered by @A.D.

> A dash

My sixth was answered by @Leslie P.

> A hyphen

My seventh was not answered

> It's a hyphen... it can be used like a pair of commas in a phrase within a sentence or in the same sense with parentheses

My eighth was answered by @frodoskywalker

> End Parenthesis

My all is:

> :-`----)

Comment: ...what am I looking at?

Comment: @BaileyM An almost smiley face.

Comment: I threw the oddity in there to make sure no one could use the surrounding clues to find that one.

Comment: My face after reading the actual answer:    >:-`----(

Comment: I was hoping the answer would be "Why the long face?" hehe

Comment: Now I know why you weren't answering my questions. Greatly disappointed, I must say. I was expecting something more.. intelligent-y.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this will help someone get closer...

My first is part of your digestive system, but you sometimes use only half of me.

> Colon

My second is sometimes called what people sometimes call the shark hanging in the Smithsonian.

> 

My third is my mom, once removed from Matilda and re-moved again.

> 

My fourth is a greeting to my friend who is named after the end.

> Hyphen ("Hi, fin!")

My fifth is a really fast run.

> Dash

My sixth is in the number three.

> Ellipsis (they come in groups of 3)

My seventh can replace my first and my last.

> 

My eighth is the last 2 of my dad's essay topics.

> Parentheses ("parent theses")

Comment: Everything but my sixth is correct

Comment: @awesomepi Would your sixth happen to be `#`?

Comment: @ace No, I do not know why everyone is assuming that the clue must mean it is inside of "3"... (hint)

Comment: I don't think everyone is assuming that. I considered that it might be some subset of "thenumberthree" or perhaps be a space, since there are spaces in that phrase. I couldn't find the name of any symbol in that string, and the space thing seemed like a stretch...

Comment: Is this building up to some kind of emoticon? With the first, fourth, fifth, and eighth, we have :  --  )

Comment: The third one is tilda ~ . I thought the common link would be symbols in the numeric row (above QWERTY) on keyboard, but it doesn't match mine.

Comment: The third one actually isn't tilde, even though it makes sense. Awesomepi revealed that on A.D.'s answer.

Comment: @awesomepi could the 3rd be lamda?

Comment: @AndrewSmith No... I believe the others have ascertained that they are all punctuation marks.

Comment: @awesomepi hmm, ok. Another question: in "my sixth" does "the number three" represent the statement to solve "my third"?

Comment: @AndrewSmith No, but it does refer to "my third".

Comment: Hey frodo don't forget about this! :o

Comment: I think the second one is Curly Brackets - they're sometimes referred to as shark jaws (Jaws could be the nickname?)

Comment: I wonder if this is an operator precedence table for some language? `:`, `{}`, `~`, `--` (or binary `-` and unary `-`), `?:` (ternary operator) (or even just `1/3`, given the hint), TBD, `()`. I can't think of any language that match, though. Or is it some obfuscated code in Perl or BASH?

Comment: I think the eighth would more precisely be "closing/ending parentheses", ie just ")". That means the seventh could replace ":)", which means it might be the ASCII smiley face?

Comment: @frodoskywalker Based on Hint #3, I think the second is the same as the fourth:  "high fin" = hyphen.  Still no idea what the complete solution is, though.  From what I've gathered, it looks like this so far (boxes are unknowns): `:-☐-—☐☐()`

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain But what would the last hint "my second is made of parts" mean then?

Comment: @Hackiisan The answer is made of 2 parts (words): "high" and "fin".

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain ah. I was thinking it was the apostrophe ("a posh trophy"), which might also work.

Comment: Made of parts could just be a reference to using both orientations of the curly braces? i.e. {} is made up of two "parts" or individual characters, since it is the combination of an open and closed bracket that we refer to as shark jaws.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> punctuation marks

My first is part of your digestive system, but you sometimes use only half of me.

> it's the colon, but sometimes we use semi-colon or semicolon

My second is sometimes called what people sometimes call the shark hanging in the Smithsonian.

> I have no clues for that one

My third is my mom, once removed from Matilda and re-moved again.

> it's a tilde but in Spanish. Because $-(Ma - Matilda) = -(-tilda) = tilda$

My fourth is a greeting to my friend, named after the end.

> I have no clues for that one

My fifth is a really fast run.

> it's a dash

My sixth is in the number three.

> I am not sure about that one, but I guess it's parenthesis because 3 looks a little bit as stacked parenthesis

My seventh can replace my first and last.

> it's an exclamation mark or a question mark

My eighth is the last of my dad's essays.

> it's a period

Comment: You need to figure out the others to get it right: only 2 are right

Comment: @awesomepi could you point out which are correct?

Comment: My first and my fifth.

Comment: @awesomepi thanks. I need to work again on that :)

Answer (score 1):

Some more of the puzzle, based off of frodo's answer. (Lots of guesses here)

My second is sometimes called what people sometimes call the shark hanging in the Smithsonian.

> Jaws, so maybe **{ }**?

My sixth is in the number three.

> Clue #3 has an extra **hyphen**.

My seventh can replace my first and my last.

> A **semicolon** can be used to combine two halves of a sentence, similarly to a colon and parentheses.

If these guesses are right, the answer looks like the following (square = unknown).. unfortunately, I still have no idea what it's supposed to be.

> :{}☐---;()