# What dissected animal am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

*My first's an incredible youngster.

My second takes time to complete.

My third's an acrobatic contraption.

My fourth can be used to compete.*

*My fifth can mean one plus one half.

My sixth is a final two tether.*

*My seventh will make all the difference.*

***What am I when my parts come together?***

---

**Hint #1:**

> Each line references a single word, with each word being pretty much unrelated to the desired animal. Once the words are interpreted correctly, you'll find the name of the dissected animal I seek. Keep in mind that the spacing is intentional.

**Hint #2/Clarification:**

> Clarification first: I accidentally lied. One of the answers is actually two words. A few of the words are similar/synonymous, so finding one will help you find the rest. For the first line, one of the words would be more correct as a *proper noun*.

Comment: is each part a Word or a single english letter?

Comment: @kanchirk I can't really answer that without giving away part of the puzzle.

Comment: Just to confirm the title: The answer is a single specific species of an animal?

Comment: @IfTrue it's not as specific as "Mexican Spiny Hairless Mouse", but to an extent, yeah.

Comment: @BaileyM Cool thanks :P Are you able to clarify the breaks between the first set of four clues the second set of two and the final (seventhe clue) on its own having meaning or was it just formatting misalignment?

Comment: @IfTrue there are no mistakes in the formatting for this puzzle!

Comment: Are these clues at first letter connected to organs? also do you literally mean animal?

Comment: @moonbutt74 I do literally mean animal.

Comment: Inspired by [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15437/my-eight-pieces-together) I assume. :) I had a bunch of notes for this exact idea myself too. Great minds I guess. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Second Attempt**

My first's an incredible youngster.

> Dash -

My second takes time to complete.

> a period is a length or portion of time or "."

My third's an acrobatic contraption.

> a trapeze which has a horizontal bar -

My fourth can be used to compete.

> Points! .

My fifth can mean one plus one half.

> . 1.5 take the dot out of it

My sixth is a final two tether.

> - in a tournament bracket the final two teams are represented with a - between them

My seventh will make all the difference.

> - you can find the difference of two numbers by subtracting them -

I believe it's,

> **-.-.  .-  -** = Cat

---

**First Wrong Attempt**

My first's an incredible youngster.

> Thomas Young, I'm basing the rest of my answers off this

My second takes time to complete.

> Everything, he was said to be the last man to know everything

My third's an acrobatic contraption.

> Springboard, Young's modulus is used to determine stress on the body and prior to that Hooke's law was used to determine deformation

My fourth can be used to compete.

> Time, he was part of a commission

My fifth can mean one plus one half.

> Interference, when two waves are out of phase the cause interference demonstrated by the Double-slit experiment

My sixth is a final two tether.

> Natural [Fast arm-swing tether](http://patents.justia.com/patent/20080076646)

My seventh will make all the difference.

> Genius, Thomas Young was a genius

I believe it's,

> Test in g. Animal testing dissected

Comment: Maybe fraction? 1 1/2 , maybe irrational ? -ly

Comment: @moonbutt74 Fractions aren't irrational, by definition.

Comment: @Zandar , thanks, i'm not very math smart, what about irreduceable? That would be wrong right? Also is the fraction became 1.5 would that then be irrational?

Comment: @moonbutt74 An irrational number is one which can't be expressed as a ratio of two integers, ie as a fraction. Regardless of how you write a fraction, it's still able to be expressed as one, so it's rational. The usual examples of irrational numbers are square roots of non-square numbers, pi and e. I suppose 3/2 would be irreducible, in that it's using the smallest numbers possible, but the riddle just says "one plus one half" which doesn't actually specify any way of writing it.

Comment: The prefix for "one and a half" is *sesqui*, as in *sesquiannual tag cleanup*.

Comment: I'll stop you right there, before you fall further down this rabbit hole - you've picked the wrong word to be proper in the first clue.

Comment: @BaileyM I went all the way down the rabbit hole. Oh well I feel like it's definitely an interesting answer and I learned a lot about Thomas Young

Comment: @SirParselot yeah, I'll give you that! It's certainly an interesting one. :) Since you've worked so hard, I'll throw you another bone. Each of the seven words is *not* indicative of a single letter. The final answer is shorter than seven letters long.

Comment: Could the first one be "baby Einstein"?

Comment: @dpwilson I was thinking the proper noun was in the first clue itself, not the answer. That being said, the answer to the first clue could easily be proper as well

Comment: @SirParselot: Good point; I suppose it does make more sense that a word in the clue is proper. We know it's not Youngster, so presumably it's either First or Incredible. I can't think of any time when they're proper nouns, though.

Comment: D'oh, it's Incredible. One of the kids from The Incredibles.

Comment: You've got the first one right, but the theme is not running, and each clue's answer is a different *word* (though some might mean the same thing). You know that the final answer is fewer than seven letters long. How could "dash" be part of a letter?

Comment: @BaileyM I just threw something down to look at it. Updates on the way!

Comment: Morse code time!

Comment: Normally I wouldn't be so quick to correct you, but I want this to be solved! I'm proud of this one. :P

Comment: @SirParselot, you're just filling your answers in with mine :(

Comment: @dpwilson Oh, sorry... I didn't notice you posted an answer. We are on the same wavelength apparently

Comment: You're right about your animal, wrong about a few of the clues, namely your second, third, and fourth. @dpwilson has the right answer for third (being the two-word phrase). I had different reasoning for fifth and sixth, but your answer is just as good there. If you can determine two and four correctly (hint: each word is *different*, though some are synonymous) I'll give you the ol' green check!

Comment: I intended for 'points' to be used to compete, but your answer is complete enough. :)

Comment: @BaileyM Oh that makes a lot more sense than ball. That one was bugging me so much! What did you have in mind for the fifth and sixth?

Answer (score 5):

Partial solution; hopefully someone can help me fill in the rest.

Is it...

> A cat?

My first's an incredible youngster.

> Dash from The Incredibles --> Dash

My second takes time to complete.

> 

My third's an acrobatic contraption.

> A trapeze, which contains a horizontal bar --> Dash

My fourth can be used to compete.

> 

My fifth can mean one plus one half.

> A period, as in the decimal 1.5 --> Dot

My sixth is a final two tether.

> A line connecting the final two members of a bracket --> Dash

My seventh will make all the difference.

> 

What am I when my parts come together?

> A cat. In Morse code, C = – • – •, A = • –, and T = –. Using the spacing, this corresponds to the answers to the given clues.

Comment: My second takes time to complete.

A period.

My fourth can be used to compete.

A point.

My seventh will make all the difference.

Subtraction.

Answer (score -3):

My first's an incredible youngster.

> B as in Spelling Bee

My second takes time to complete.

> A as in Answer of Q & A

My third's an acrobatic contraption.

> C as in Circus tent

My fourth can be used to compete.

> T -> Target

My fifth can mean one plus one half.

> E -> onE + on -> E ? (I doubt this)

My sixth is a final two tether.

> RI -> Infra Red -> or Rigorous Imprisonment

My seventh will make all the difference.

> A as in Attitude

What am I when my parts come together?

> BACTERIA

Comment: These all seem very tenuous.